# Can't save a dqn model using a custom environment

Tags: python, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I was trying to make a reinforcement learning ai for a chrome dino game. I was following a guide on this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vahwuupy81A, but changed something when I had errors. The problem I am experiencing now is that I can't save my model and I don't even know if it is actually training.

here is my code:

```
from mss import mss
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
import time
import pyautogui
from gymnasium import Env
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from gymnasium.spaces import Box, Discrete
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import os
from stable_baselines3.common.callbacks import BaseCallback
from stable_baselines3.common import env_checker
from stable_baselines3 import DQN


pyautogui.PAUSE=0
class WebGame(Env):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.observation_space = Box(low=0, high=255, shape=(1, 83, 100), dtype=np.uint8)
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        self.cap = mss()
        self.gameLocation = (0, 600, 500, 900)
        self.doneLocation = (565, 580, 850, 635)
        pass
    def step(self, action):
        actionMap={
            0:'up',
            1:'down',
            2:'no_op'
        }
        if action!=2:
            pyautogui.press(actionMap[action])
        done, doneCap=self.getDone()
        newObs=self.getObservation()
        reward=1
        info={}
        return newObs, reward, done, done, info
    def reset(self, seed=None):
        time.sleep(1)
        pyautogui.press("up")
        initial_observation = self.getObservation()
        info = {}  # You can populate this info dictionary if needed
        return initial_observation, info
    def getObservation(self):
        raw=np.array(ImageGrab.grab(self.gameLocation))[:, :, :3]
        gray=cv2.cvtColor(raw, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        resized=cv2.resize(gray, (100, 83))
        channel=np.reshape(resized, (1, 83, 100))
        return channel
    def getDone(self):
        raw=ImageGrab.grab(self.doneLocation)
        done_strings='G&G AME\n'
        done=False
        res=pytesseract.image_to_string(raw)
        if res==done_strings:
            done=True
        return done, raw

time.sleep(2)
env = WebGame()
env_checker.check_env(env)
class TrainAndLoggingCallback(BaseCallback):
    def __init__(self, checkFreq, savePath, verbose=1):
       super(TrainAndLoggingCallback, self).__init__(verbose)
       self.checkFreq=checkFreq
       self.savePath=savePath
    def _init_callback(self):
        if self.savePath is not None:
            os.makedirs(self.savePath, exist_ok=True)
    def _on_step(self):
        if self.n_calls % self.checkFreq==0:
            modelPath=os.path.join(self.savePath, f'best_model_{self.n_calls}')
            self.model.save(modelPath)
CHECKPOINT_DIR='./train/'
LOG_DIR='./logs/'
callback=TrainAndLoggingCallback(checkFreq=1, savePath=CHECKPOINT_DIR)
model=DQN('CnnPolicy', env, tensorboard_log=LOG_DIR, verbose=1, buffer_size=900000, learning_starts=0)
model.learn(total_timesteps=88000, log_interval=1)
#model.load(os.path.join('best_model.7z'))
"""for episode in range(5):
    obs=env.reset()
    done=False
    totalReward=0
    while not done:
        action, _ = model.predict(obs)
        obs, reward, done, _, info=env.step(int(action))
        totalReward+=reward"""
```

I have two folders in the same folder as my python file: train and logs, and both of them are empty even after training. I think the problem is that I didn't use callback variable, but if I use it python says ...got an unexpected argument.

What is the problem?

Do you know any easier ways to create a self-learning ai for your custom environment (for instance for a web game, as I was trying to do)?